# Is there a command to check the network bandwidth of a server? (linux)

Tags: networking, centos, bandwidth

I am trying to compare different cloud server providers and one thing I am interested is the network bandwidth like 1Gb/s. Many vendors are not explicit in this respect.

Is there a way in Centos to check for this information? (I mean the "theoretical value", in a way like you use command line to grep the cpu info; not manually downloading files to test speed.)

Comment: Do you mean the speed setting on the NIC?

Comment: ^ if so, then you would use ethtool <interface>

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the line speed that the emulated driver is giving then something like:

```
$ ethtool eth0 | egrep 'Speed|Duplex'
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
```

However it's virtualised so the values are pretty meaningless.

It is impossible to tell from the Client OS what the usable link actually is without measuring a transfer.  Even with that the values will vary depending on what other VMs on the host are doing at the time.  This is why the vendors are not explicit.

They may have an SLA for the bandwidth though in the agreement somewhere.